# Drag-Drop Not Initiated When Debugging After DoDragDrop Fires In Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, drag-and-drop

I have noticed a frustrating problem during which a standard Winform control will not enter a drag-drop operation during a debug session as it should after calling the control's DoDragDrop method. The source control (from which the drag-drop operation is initiated) acts as if it doesn't support drag-and-drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it turns out that I was running a debug session in a second instance of Visual Studio 2017. When I stopped running that second debug-session instance of Visual Studio (I was able to keep Visual Studio open, I just had to stop my debug session), the drag operation in the first debug-session instance of Visual Studio began working as expected.

Clearly, drag-and-drop *should* work in two debug sessions open at the same time in two different Visual Studio instances--and sometimes it *does* on my system. But occasionally something happens (I'm not yet sure what) to "corrupt" the VS IDE or the .NET subsystem that causes a Winform drag operation from no longer functioning.

This behavior occurs even after rebooting and happens in the latest VS Enterprise 2017 IDE (Ver 15.5.6) with .NET 4.7.02556.

I realize that this problem and its solution is rather nebulous but I felt it was enough to be useful here (and I invested a lot of time figuring out what was going on!).

Comment: I have to wait two days to do that--but I will, and thank you for the reminder. :)

Comment: Thanks for your sharing again. It would be helpful for other community members who get the same issue. Have a nice day:)